# Weird Issue with cvStartFindContours?

Tags: c++, image, opencv, contour

Whenever I pass in an image to cvStartFindContours, instead of finding the contours, my image turns completely black. I have absolutely no idea why. I know this isn't caused by another part of the code even if I comment everything out, but leave in the function call to cvStartFindContours, my image still turns black. However the second I comment out the call to cvStartFindContours, my image remains normal. Why is this happening? The image I pass in (skinMask) is a 8 bit, 1 channel image (IPL_DEPTH_8U) with CONTAINS data. (it isn't black it has pieces of white on it).

Why is my image turning black? Thanks

```
void connectedComponents ()
{
     cvMorphologyEx (skinMask, skinMask, 0, 0, CV_MOP_OPEN, 1);
     cvMorphologyEx (skinMask, skinMask, 0, 0, CV_MOP_CLOSE, 1);

     CvMemStorage *connectedCompStorage = cvCreateMemStorage (0);
     CvSeq *temp = NULL; //used to loop through contour perimeter checking
     CvSeq *connectedComp = NULL; //stores all derived connected component contours

     CvContourScanner connectedCompScanner = cvStartFindContours (skinMask, connectedCompStorage); //FUNCTION CALL CAUSING PROBLEMS

     while ((temp = cvFindNextContour (connectedCompScanner)) != NULL)
     {
         double perimeter = cvContourPerimeter (temp);

         if (perimeter < CC_PERIMETER_THRESH)
         {
             cvSubstituteContour (connectedCompScanner, NULL);
         }

         else
         {
             temp = cvApproxPoly (temp, sizeof (CvContour), connectedCompStorage, CV_POLY_APPROX_DP, 2, 0);
             cvSubstituteContour (connectedCompScanner, temp);
         }
     }

     connectedComp = cvEndFindContours (&connectedCompScanner);

     cvZero (skinMask);

     for (temp = connectedComp; temp != NULL; temp = temp -> h_next);
     {
         cvDrawContours (skinMask, temp, cvScalar (255, 255, 255), cvScalar (0, 0, 0), -1,   CV_FILLED, 8);
     }

     cvReleaseMemStorage (&connectedCompStorage);
}
```

Comment: Did you debug your code? Does any of the contours have a perimeter bigger than your threshold?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been bitten by this as well. From the OpenCV documentation for `findContours`:

> image – Source, an 8-bit single-channel image. Non-zero pixels are
>   treated as 1’s. Zero pixels remain 0’s, so the image is treated as
>   binary . You can use `compare()` , `inRange()` , `threshold()` ,
>   `adaptiveThreshold()` , `Canny()` , and others to create a binary image
>   out of a grayscale or color one. **The function modifies the image while
>   extracting the contours.**

So, if you don't want your `skinMask` image to be modified, you need to pass in a copy of it...

Comment: THANK YOU! :D
Ive been trying to figure this out for 2 weeks, and you solved it perfectly! :)

Comment: No problem! Sorry you spent 2 weeks on it :( Stack Overflow is quite an amazing resource!